# Search from large number of data by large number of keywords one by one at client side using PHP or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatable

Search from large number of data by large number of keywords one by one at client side using PHP or JavaScript

> Table1 - Contain data in number of lakhs (column : id, title, description)
>
> Table2 - Contain 25k keywords. (column : id, keyword)

Now i want to search data by one by one keyword in Table1, but i want to search from only 2-3k data  from Table1 (only in title, description column).

So i planed, First to get those 2-3k data in some object like Datatable, Array etc. and after this, search one by one keyword in object and when any keyword match in Table1(only in title, description column). object store ID of those data in MATCH[] array and not match data ID store in NOTMATCH[] array.

Example: Table1 (100 000 rows)

```
id  title                           description
1   dell laptop                     laptop i3 5000 xyz
2   hp machine                      hp xyz abc utr
3   supply motor 1500               Decorative Watches
4   Deep Groove Drill Ball Bearing  Deep Hole Drill
```

Example: Table2 (26 000 rows)

```
id             keyword
1              dell
2              Drill
```

This is my code. i want some improvement in it for fast..or other logic. like bootstrap datatable Client-side search process is work when any keyword enter in search input and showing result.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
        //this data from table1
        $data = array(
            "0"=>array(
                "ID" => "1234",
                "title" => "dell laptop",
                "description" => "dell laptop i3 5000 xyz",
                ),
            "1"=>array(
                "ID" => "1238",
                "title" => "hp machine",
                "description" => "hp xyz abc utr",
            ),
            "2"=>array(
                "ID" => "1240",
                "title" => "supply motor 1500",
                "description" => "Decorative Watches",
            ),
            "3"=>array(
                "ID" => "1245",
                "title" => "Deep Groove Drill Ball Bearing",
                "description" => "Deep Hole Drill",
            ),
        );

        $MATCH =array();
        $NOTMATCH =array();

        $keywords =array('dell','watches'); //this data from table2
        echo "<pre>";

        for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
        {
            $ID = $data[$i]['ID'];
            foreach($keywords as $value)
            {
                $pattern = "/$value/i";  //contains pattern
                $dd = preg_grep($pattern, $data[$i]);
                if($dd)
                {
                    if(isset($NOTMATCH[$ID]))
                    {
                        unset($NOTMATCH[$ID]); 
                    }
                    $MATCH[$ID] = $ID;
                    break 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $NOTMATCH[$ID] = $ID;
                }
            }
        }
        echo "****Found****<BR>";
        print_r($MATCH);
        echo "<BR>****NOT Found****<BR>";
        print_r($NOTMATCH);
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

So how can i write code as per my planed.

Comment: Your query is selected by ID? Or you can select all then filter with JS?

Comment: Thanks @SimoneRossaini for your reply. First i will select all data.

Comment: If is according with your website, i can post a simply js filter so do you have all table with all records and filter will disable td from your input

Comment: Yes i have two tables with all records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best code which i wanted, it will search around 26000 keywords one by one in around 2000 data using PHP Array. It is fast better than searching in SQL table by queries.

```
<?php
$data = array(); // Array value added from mysql database table 2000 rows (columns : ID, title, description)
$keywords = array(); // Array value added from mysql database table 26000 rows (column : keyword)
if (!$data)
{
    echo "<script> alert('No Data available for Search...!');</script>";
    exit();
}
$MATCHID =array();
$NOTMATCHID =array();

set_time_limit(0);// 0 = NOLIMIT
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
{
    $ID = $data[$i]['ID'];
    foreach($keywords as $value)
    {
        $pattern = "/ ".$value." /i";  //contains pattern
        $dd = preg_grep($pattern, $data[$i]);
        if($dd)
        {
            if (in_array($ID, $NOTMATCHID))
            {
                $NOTMATCHID = array_diff($NOTMATCHID, array($ID));
            }
            $MATCHID[] = $ID;
            break 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!in_array($ID, $NOTMATCHID))
            {
                $NOTMATCHID[] = $ID;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
echo "****Found IDs****<BR>";
print_r($MATCHID);
echo "<BR>****NOT Found IDs****<BR>";
print_r($NOTMATCHID);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Example according with you (obv you will adapt to your code):

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px; /* Increase font-size */
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left; /* Left-align text */
  padding: 12px; /* Add padding */
}

#myTable tr {
  /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">ROW 1</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">ROW 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>RESULT</td>
    <td>RESULT 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>RESULT 3</td>
    <td>RESULT 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>RESULT 5</td>
    <td>RESULT 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>RESULT 7</td>
    <td>RESULT 8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> Tip: Remove toUpperCase() if you want to perform a case-sensitive search.
>
> Tip: Change tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0] to [1] if you want to search for "Country" (index 1) instead of "Name" (index 0).

Comment: How can i store Id for those data which found in search..(When any keyword match in Table1 object store ID of those data in MATCH[] array and not match data ID store in NOTMATCH[] array.)

Comment: You can use AJAX for control input so where user write for example ''1'' in input, ajax will do what you want.